# NPM CI takes different amount of time on the same Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, npm, dependencies, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a pipeline running on Jenkins that does a few steps before running my lint, unit and integration tests. One of those steps is to install the dependencies. That's done using `npm ci`.

I'm trying to figure out what is causing this step to take different amount of time, sometimes it's around 15sec sometimes more than 1min. Unfortunately it's been hard to find anything online that explains this random behaviour.

[image]

[image]

The pipeline is running on the same code base, so no changes have been made to the dependencies.

Would be very helpful if someone could explain what is causing this difference, or point me to a resource that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expected behaviour and you should not expect always the same amount of time.

There are many factors while installing node modules, for example

- NPM registry server might be busy mean more laod so you can expect latency
- Your local server stats, for instance, what if your jenkins CPU is 100% then can I expect constant installation time?
- Network traffic etc

So you should not rely on the registry to response you always on the same amount of time.

you can reproduce easily by adding and removing node modules.

[image]

If you hate latency that you can configure your own [NPM registry](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio).

> Verdaccio is a simple, zero-config-required local private npm
>   registry. No need for an entire database just to get started!
>   Verdaccio comes out of the box with its own tiny database, and the
>   ability to proxy other registries (eg. npmjs.org), caching the
>   downloaded modules along the way. For those looking to extend their
>   storage capabilities, Verdaccio supports various community-made
>   plugins to hook into services such as Amazon's s3, Google Cloud
>   Storage or create your own